# Python: how to print an AD user's mobile number?

Tags: python, active-directory, contacts

I'm again a bit stuck I'm afraid. I've been scouring the internet for anyone who might've needed to do the same thing, and there does appear to be a few who've managed it, but I just cannot fit all the pieces of the puzzle together.

In short: I need to get the mobile numbers for all users listed in AD.

The simplest and easiest way so far appears to be Tim Golden's active_directory module, which brings me to how my code looks so far (essentially a straight copy-and-paste of his example coding):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import active_directory

def main():

    for user in active_directory.search (objectCategory='Person', objectClass='User'):
      print user

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The code above works a treat, but I just cannot figure out how to include the mobile phone number in the output. I have no idea what the field's name is in AD/ LDAP, but I suspect it's 'MobileTelephoneNumber'.

Does anyone perhaps know of a quick and dirty way to include the mobile number for each user? It doesn't have to only be the number, could be all contact details.

**EDIT**:

I'm taking a wild guess that I need to modify the coding slightly to something like this:

```
    for user, number in active_directory.search (objectCategory='Person', objectClass='User', objectClass='MobileTelephoneNumber'):
      print user, number
```

That doesn't seem to work though. I'm sure there must be some sort of way to do this, I just can't seem to figure it out though. If I could figure out exactly where the number is stored in AD I'd probably be able to figure it out eventually, but there just does not seem to be too much info on it, or at least info I'm able to comprehend.

**EDIT #2:**
Thanks to ivan_pozdeev, I'm able to see the attribute I need ("mobile"), but I still have no idea of how to actually print it via Python... Is there a way to print an LDAP object's full attributes via Python, and if so, via the active_directory module?

**EDIT #3:**
Nevermind, think I got it now. Once I have code that works more or less, I'll post it back here just in case someone else out there ever runs into the same brickwall I have.

**EDIT #4:**
Turns out I'm a bit of an idiot. This is apparently as easy as using the following code:

```
    for user in active_directory.search (objectCategory='Person', objectClass='User'):
      print user, user.mobile
```

Thanks again for the help ivan_pozdeev, appreciate it :)

Comment: [AD explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907.aspx) might help to figure out AD records' contents. As for how to use `active_directory.search`, there are docs, source and command-line mode.

Comment: Thanks for the AD explorer link, but as far as documentation around active_directory.search is concerned, the only ones I've managed to hunt down so far are from Tim Golden's site, which doesn't explain much around obtaining phone numbers specifically. I think my LDAP knowledge is letting me down a bit here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See EDIT #4 in my post. This wasn't really solved by me either, but thanks to user ivan_pozdeev pointing me in the right direction.

To anyone else stumbling onto this post in future, get AD Explorer, then look at the name(s) of the attributes you wish to print. If the attribute name is "mobile", you can get it by specifying user.mobile (as in my case).

And Tim Golden, if you ever read this, excellent work on the active_directory module. It's just managed to save my bacon.